# Angular 6 reuse onclick event

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a onclick event that will redirect to a new page carrying the correct query params. I am going to use this same function in about 5 other places, I am trying to put it in a common place to be reused instead of writing the same code over and over again. Here is just a short example. Hopefully I can get some understand how to share it between components.

The service layer where I moved the function to that will be shared among multiple components. onViolatorClick is what will need to be shared.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutesService {

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  public onViolatorClick(value): void {
    alert(value);

    this.router.navigate(["vio-violator"], {
      queryParams: { dmid: value }
    });
  }
}
```

HTML, basic but I know it works if the function was inside the component

```
<button (click)="onViolatorClick(dataItem.dmid)">Test!</button>
```

Component, this is where I am unsure how to use onViolatorClick correctly

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {MyMappService} from "./my-mapp.service";
import {MyMappProducts} from "./my-mapp.model";
import { onViolatorClick } from '../../shared/routes/routes.service';

@Component({
    templateUrl: "./my-mapp.component.html"
})
export class MyMappComponent implements OnInit {
    mid: string;
    getMyMappProducts: MyMappProducts[];

    constructor(
        private myMappService: MyMappService,
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getMyMappProducts = [];
        this.myMappService.getMyMappProducts("1").subscribe(res => this.getMyMappProducts = res);
    }
}
```

Comment: in your constructor write `this.onViolatorClick = onViolatorClick.bind(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the service in your constructor of your component

```
constructor(private routesService: RoutesService){}
```

and then use it like this

```
this.routesService.onViolatorClick()
```

Comment: Great, that did the trick. Makes much more sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your service in your component.ts file's constructor file.

1) import service file in ts file.

2) add service file in constructor.

```
constructor(private service : RoutesService)
```

3) Now you can easily call method.

```
this.service.onViolatorClick();
```